# Sample Windows Phone 7 pivot implementations

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any suggestions on good sample pivot implementations for Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roger Peters' [Example Pivot Control for Windows Phone 7](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/content/example-pivot-control-windows-phone-7) looks like a good starting point.

Comment: The official Microsoft Pivot control is now released, so you should use that one.

Comment: does anyone have a link to an opensource Pivot control implementation for WPF and/or Silverlight?